# Job opportunity in graphics and web design

Tags: job-description

I am a junior software developer, with just 4 months experience.

I am pursuing with this job currently. I want to shift my career to graphics and web design. I know HTML, CSS and JS, and I've started learning Photoshop and illustrator.

I've applied to many companies, but all of them are asking for me to show the practical client projects which I have done. But I do not have that much vast experience. How hard it is to get a job in graphics and web designing as a fresher?

Comment: Voting to close, career advice and localised to the poster's locale.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, in such cases, potential employers want to see a portfolio of what you've done until that point, or at least the most impressive/relevant works.

Even if you didn't work as a graphics designer or did such projects for clients, you should at least have some personal projects to show, things you did in your free time to learn the skills and/or improve them.

They will look at them and probably ask you a bunch of questions about how you did what you did and why you did it that way. Also, you should probably not cheat and show other people's stuff; even if you get away with it, it will come to bite you later. So I recommend having some proof that you are the author of the works (still having the Photoshop projects on your computer should be sufficient for this).

If you still don't manage to get jobs this way, try to pursue more junior positions or even internships in that field, instead of higher profile positions; you probably have better chances that way.

Comment: There's no probably -- don't cheat. Build a portfolio of your own work.